# getComputedStyle() returns empty strings on FF when instead Crome returns a computed value

Tags: javascript, css

I am using `window.getComputedStyle()` in order to get CSS values for properties:

- borderRadius
- borderStyle
- borderWidth
- borderColor

I have noticed that latest FF returns empty strings, Chrome instead returns computed values with also units:

FF:

```
"borderRadius":"","borderStyle":"","borderWidth":"","borderColor":""
```

Chrome:

```
"borderRadius":"0px","borderStyle":"none","borderWidth":"0px","borderColor":"rgb(0, 0, 0)"}
```

I would like to know:

- Is this discrepancy caused by a known bug?
- Do you know a way to force FF to return values as Chrome? (I am aware I can add defaults with some conditions but I would to use a native solutions if possible).

```js
    (function (window) {
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
            let elmTarget = document.querySelector('#target'),
                elmResult = document.querySelector('#result');

            let styles = window.getComputedStyle(elmTarget),
                result = {
                    borderRadius: styles.borderRadius,
                    borderStyle: styles.borderStyle,
                    borderWidth: styles.borderWidth,
                    borderColor: styles.borderColor
                },
                resultStr = JSON.stringify(result);
            console.log(resultStr);
            elmResult.innerHTML = resultStr;
        });
    })(window);
```

```css
        #target {
            background-color: blue;
            width: 100px;
            height: 50px;
        }
```

```html
    <div id="target"></div>
    <div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Shorthands.**

In FF you need to get all separately.

```
border-left-style
border-top-style
border-bottom-style
border-right-style

border-left-width
...
```

with `border-radius` being even longer :

```
border-top-left-radius
border-top-right-radius
...
```

```js
(function(window) {
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    let elmTarget = document.querySelector('#target'),
      elmResult = document.querySelector('#result');

    let styles = window.getComputedStyle(elmTarget),
      result = {
        borderTopLeftRadius: styles.borderTopLeftRadius,
        borderTopRightRadius: styles.borderTopRightRadius,
        borderBottomLeftRadius: styles.borderBottomLeftRadius,
        borderBottomRightRadius: styles.borderBottomRightRadius,

        borderLeftStyle: styles.borderLeftStyle,
        borderTopStyle: styles.borderTopStyle,
        borderBottomStyle: styles.borderBottomStyle,
        borderRightStyle: styles.borderRightStyle,

        borderLeftWidth: styles.borderLeftWidth,
        borderTopWidth: styles.borderTopWidth,
        borderRightWidth: styles.borderRightWidth,
        borderBottomWidth: styles.borderBottomWidth,

        borderLeftColor: styles.borderLeftColor,
        borderTopColor: styles.borderTopColor,
        borderBottomColor: styles.borderBottomColor,
        borderRightColor: styles.borderRightColor,
      },
      resultStr = JSON.stringify(result);
    console.log(resultStr);
    elmResult.innerHTML = resultStr;
  });
})(window);
```

```css
#target {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="target"></div>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: @GibboK, same : `borderLeftColor` etc. I'm writting a snippet with all. radius is even more complicated (`borderTopLeftRadius`)

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I also added more info about why of this behavior in FF.

Answer (score 0):

The reasons why `getComputedStyle()` returns empty strings on FF and not in Chrome seems related to missing specification which Chrome instead implements instead. More information at the link below:

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=137688